# MediatR customized behaviour pipeline

Tags: c#, behavior, mediatr

guys.

I have a strange question about MediatR behaviours (I'm a newbie in MediatR).
Let me have a `RequestHandler<Request1, Response1>` and `RequestHandler<Request2, Response2>`.  I want to have 2 different behaviours for both:for example, `MyBehavior1<Request1, Response2>`, `MyBehaviour2<Request1, Response1>` for `RequestHandler<Request1, Response1>` and `MyBehavior1<Request2, Response2>`, `MyBehavior3<Request2, Response2>`.
But as I see, all `MyBehaviour` will be called for both handlers. IS it possible to customize the list of behaviours for concrete handler?

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer is no, it will not work,  Mediator will match the type of request and response from that behavior to the registered handler that implement both of them, if the behavior didn't match any handler signature it will not get invoked in mediator pipeline, I tried to do trick using `object`, `anonymous`,`dynamic` as response in Behavior but NO, they are may doing a strict checking by name, you may try built in [action filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#action-filters) redirect to another endpoint which has a diff.. response.

Comment: @ElSayed thank you. Now I'm on the way to create resolver in the pipeline, which check is current behaviour realize concrete interface, connected with the handler. Hope, this helps me...